# How to get Hessian Matrix from python minimize function?

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

Is there any way that we could get the Hessian matrix (so as to calculate the standard error) after getting the optimization result through `scipy.minimize` function?

The parameter of hessian in the minimize function seems to be input instead of an output.

```
from scipy import minimize

opt = minimize(logitfn, args=df, x0=x_start, method='Nelder-Mead')
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `'L-BFGS-B'` method, and then:

```
opt.hess_inv.todense()
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, is it the Hessian or its inverse ? If the full hessian is needed, shoudn't be `np.linalg.inv(opt.hess_inv.todense())` ???

Comment: And what about the standard error ?

Answer (score 1):

Given a function f and initial point x0, and assuming we use L-BFGS-B, then the following code works:

```
opt = minimize(f, x0=x0, method='L-BFGS-B')
B = opt.hess_inv  # LinearOperator object
B = B * np.identity(B.shape[1])  # numpy array
```