# Covariance deviation when using method L-BFGS-B of scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, minimize, covariance-matrix

When assessing covariance matrix with `scipy.optimize.minimize` for a simple LLS problem, I have got significant deviation when using the method `L-BFGS-B`. After a lot of research, I have created a detailed MCVE to highlight the issue.

### MCVE

#### Then handy `curve_fit` method

Let say we want to fit the following model to some trial dataset:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def model(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x[:, 0]**2 + b * x[:, 0] + c

np.random.seed(12345)
X = np.linspace(-1, 1, 30).reshape(-1, 1)
y = model(X, 3, 2, 1)
s = 0.1 * np.ones(y.size)
n = s * np.random.normal(size=y.size)
yn = y + n

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, X, yn, sigma=s, absolute_sigma=True)
popt, pcov

# (array([3.00876769, 2.00038216, 1.03068484]),
#  array([[ 3.29272571e-03, -1.11752553e-11, -1.17327007e-03],
#         [-1.11752553e-11,  9.35483883e-04,  2.98424026e-12],
#         [-1.17327007e-03,  2.98424026e-12,  7.51395072e-04]]))
```

The [`curve_fit`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L585) method directly provides Covariance matrix which is considered as the expected result. Now we want to reproduce this covariance matrix using different `optimize` methods.

#### Check with baseline method `least_squares`

Using the [`least_squares`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py#L241) function ([which is used by `curve_fit` under the hood](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L988)) and the [recipe](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L1002C21-L1007) `scipy` use to robustly assess the covariance leads to compliant results:

```
def residuals_factory(x, y, sigma=1.):
    def wrapped(beta):
        return (y - model(x, *beta)) / sigma
    return wrapped

residuals = residuals_factory(X, yn, sigma=s)

sol0 = optimize.least_squares(residuals, x0=[1, 1, 1])
#     message: `xtol` termination condition is satisfied.
#     success: True
#      status: 3
#         fun: [-5.954e-01  9.965e-02 ... -3.855e-01  9.455e-01]
#           x: [ 3.009e+00  2.000e+00  1.031e+00]
#        cost: 16.317663438370303
#         jac: [[-1.000e+01  1.000e+01 -1.000e+01]
#               [-8.668e+00  9.310e+00 -1.000e+01]
#               ...
#               [-8.668e+00 -9.310e+00 -1.000e+01]
#               [-1.000e+01 -1.000e+01 -1.000e+01]]
#        grad: [ 1.070e-07 -1.632e-06  1.722e-07]
#  optimality: 1.632403261453419e-06
# active_mask: [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00]
#        nfev: 4
#        njev: 3

U, s, Vh = np.linalg.svd(sol0.jac, full_matrices=False)
tol = np.finfo(float).eps*s[0]*max(sol0.jac.shape)
w = s > tol
cov = (Vh[w].T/s[w]**2) @ Vh[w]

# array([[ 3.29272571e-03,  5.77282993e-12, -1.17327008e-03],
#        [ 5.77282993e-12,  9.35483875e-04,  1.14915683e-12],
#        [-1.17327008e-03,  1.14915683e-12,  7.51395089e-04]])
```

In this context we can reproduce the covariance.

#### Check with `minimize` method

Using [`minimize`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L51), we can perform the same operation by stating the Chi Squared loss function instead of residuals.

```
def loss_factory(x, y, sigma=1.):
    def wrapped(beta):
        return 0.5 * np.sum(np.power((y - model(x, *beta)) / sigma, 2))
    return wrapped

loss = loss_factory(X, yn, sigma=s)

sol1 = optimize.minimize(loss, x0=[1, 1, 1])
#  message: Optimization terminated successfully.
#  success: True
#   status: 0
#      fun: 16.31766343837042
#        x: [ 3.009e+00  2.000e+00  1.031e+00]
#      nit: 5
#      jac: [ 1.907e-06  1.192e-06 -4.768e-07]
# hess_inv: [[ 3.293e-03  1.104e-11 -1.173e-03]
#            [ 1.104e-11  9.355e-04 -1.734e-12]
#            [-1.173e-03 -1.734e-12  7.514e-04]]
#     nfev: 32
#     njev: 8
```

Again we are able to get the covariance matrix (see `hess_inv`). This also works as expected with method `BFGS`.

#### Issue with `L-BFGS-B` method

But when we use the `L-BFGS-B` method, the Inverse Hessian returned does not comply with previously computed covariance matrices:

```
sol2 = optimize.minimize(loss, x0=[1, 1, 1], method="L-BFGS-B")
#  message: CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH
#  success: True
#   status: 0
#      fun: 16.317663438454282
#        x: [ 3.009e+00  2.000e+00  1.031e+00]
#      nit: 8
#      jac: [-5.720e-05  2.917e-04 -4.182e-04]
#     nfev: 36
#     njev: 9
# hess_inv: <3x3 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>

sol2.hess_inv.todense()
# array([[ 0.03719202,  0.02371079, -0.02612526],
#        [ 0.02371079,  0.02215422, -0.01929008],
#        [-0.02612526, -0.01929008,  0.01984616]])
```

I wonder why the inverse hessian is so different in this configuration and how can I adapt this code to get the covariance matrix as I did in the three previous snippets.

#### Related questions

Below some questions I have found that are related during research but does not answer the current question:

- [How to compute standard deviation errors with scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388139/how-to-compute-standard-deviation-errors-with-scipy-optimize-least-squares)
- [In Scipy how and why does curve_fit calculate the covariance of the parameter estimates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854339/in-scipy-how-and-why-does-curve-fit-calculate-the-covariance-of-the-parameter-es)
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38115/how-do-i-interpret-the-covariance-matrix-from-a-curve-fit
- [How to get Hessian Matrix from python minimize function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754455/how-to-get-hessian-matrix-from-python-minimize-function)

#### Question

Why the method `minimize` with option `method='L-BFGS-B'` returns a so different inverse hessian and how should I fix it in order to get a proper covariance matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible with L-BFGS-B. The method uses a limited-memory approximation of the Hessian - that's what makes it have linear memory use instead of quadratic memory use. I looked to see if SciPy has any option to configure the history length to make the approximation more accurate, but I can't find any option to do this.

Comment: @NickODell There is a `m` switch on the underlying function, but it cannot by passed to minimize itself. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NickODell pointed out, method `L-BFGS-B` compute a limited memory approximation of the Hessian.

There is a `m` switch on the underlying function [`fmin_l_bfgs_b`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b), but it's not available in the [`minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html#optimize-minimize-lbfgsb) signature, therefore we cannot control how precise is this approximation.

As a workaround, Hessian matrix can be computed after minimizing:

```
from autograd import hessian

H = hessian(loss)(solution.x)
C = np.linalg.inv(H)

# array([[ 3.29272573e-03,  1.28301871e-19, -1.17327009e-03],
#        [ 2.44025127e-19,  9.35483871e-04, -6.92261149e-20],
#        [-1.17327009e-03, -3.24227332e-20,  7.51395089e-04]])
```

Which is compliant with other results.

Alternative:

```
import numdifftools

H = numdifftools.Hessian(loss)(solution.x)
C = np.linalg.inv(H)
```